# how to display a listview when clicked on the item of spinner using onitemselected listener?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have written a program which displays a spinner but i want to display a listview inside the same activity when i select any item of the spinner , i have also written a code for custom adapter to display items inside the listview and the the listviews row has 6 textviews all of which data comes from String-array defined inside strings.xml file , so need some help

Result_Date.java which has a spinner and the resources , dont know what all to call inside "onitemselected" method

```
public class Result_Date extends Activity {

ImageView iv;
String[] years = { "Select year", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004",
        "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012",
        "2013", "2014" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView lv;
String[] name;
String[] mobile;
String[] gender;
String[] age;
String[] disease;
String[] day;
String[] month;
String[] year;

int[] images = { R.drawable.photo_bg, R.drawable.photo_bg,
        R.drawable.photo_bg, R.drawable.photo_bg, R.drawable.photo_bg,
        R.drawable.photo_bg, R.drawable.photo_bg, R.drawable.photo_bg };

Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_list_year);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.btnShowYear);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBackReuslt);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1, years) {
        @Override
        //this method is used to hide the default text "Select Year" which repeats twice
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = null;

            if (position == 0) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
                tv.setHeight(0);
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                v = tv;
            } else {

                v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
            }

            parent.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            return v;
        }
    };

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Resources res = getResources();
    name = res.getStringArray(R.array.Name);
    mobile = res.getStringArray(R.array.Mobile);
    gender = res.getStringArray(R.array.Gender);
    age = res.getStringArray(R.array.Age);
    disease = res.getStringArray(R.array.DiagnosisName);
    day = res.getStringArray(R.array.day_array);
    month = res.getStringArray(R.array.month_year);
    year = res.getStringArray(R.array.year_array);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstShowYear);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), name, mobile,
            gender, age, images, day, month, year, disease);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

My CustomAdapter MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
int[] images;
String[] namearray;
String[] mobilearray;
String[] genderarray;
String[] agearray;
String[] diseasearray;
String[] dayarray;
String[] montharray;
String[] yeararray;

public MyAdapter(Context c, String[] name, String[] mobile,
        String[] gender, String[] age, int[] img, String[] disease,
        String[] day, String[] month, String[] year) {
    super(c, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.textView1, name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = c;
    this.namearray = name;
    this.mobilearray = mobile;
    this.genderarray = gender;
    this.agearray = age;
    this.diseasearray = disease;
    this.dayarray = day;
    this.montharray = month;
    this.yeararray = year;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView lv;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
    TextView text3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtGender);
    TextView text4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
    TextView text5 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDesease);
    TextView text6 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    lv = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    image.setImageResource(images[position]);
    text1.setText(namearray[position]);
    text2.setText(mobilearray[position]);
    text3.setText(genderarray[position]);
    text4.setText(agearray[position]);
    text5.setText(diseasearray[position]);
    text6.setText(dayarray[position]);
    text6.setText(montharray[position]);
    text6.setText(yeararray[position]);

    return row;
}
```

}

Do i need to write the code from defining Resources obj till setting the adapter inside onitemselected method ??
any suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the following thing:

Create a method inside my ListAdapter named for example "refreshList" that could take as parameter the data from the selected spinner item that you need to "get" the data you need to fill the list with by the spinner's value selected. For example if the data that change the list is the YEAR the function could be something like this:

```
public void refreshList(String year) {
    //Fill the arrays with the data according to the year
    namearray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Name);
    //Do loas all the data you need according to the year here
    //And the refresh the adapter
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your onItemSelected call of the spinner call that function of the ListAdapter like `adapter.refreshList(years[position])` or something like that. It's just an idea there is many ways to do this, the point is that you have a function in adapters called `notifyDataSetChanged()` that load again the list with the data currently in the list/array of data you handle inside the adapter. If the spinner selected value will change the list data then you should use that to refresh the list when the spinner value is selected. Hope it helps

Comment: sir i tried the above , but i m getting null pointer exception , storage == null

Comment: the above is just a idea, the point is for you to refresh the adapter in the spinner item change event. What you mean with "storage == null"? can you show me the new code?

Comment: public void refreshList(String years) {
   
    name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Name);
    mobile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Mobile);
    gender = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender);  
    age = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Age);
   
   disease=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DiagnosisName);
   year = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.year_array);
   
    
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
and i called it from my onitemselected method adapter.refreshList(years[position])

i know i have done wrong thats why an error, please guide me

Comment: ok, tell me what you want to achieve with the "year" selection of the spinner, what it change in the list data? coz I'm seen you just load the list from the strings but is the same data over and over? how you make your filter by year?

Comment: First a few things, extend your adapter from BaseAdapter not from ArrayAdapter, it is better for your logic, then override the getCount() method with the size of the list you will use as data. I'm seen that you use several arrays inside your adapter, if one array does't have the same size as the others you will get a OutOfBounds Exception, be careful with that.

Comment: The other thing is that you need to use the convertView in your getView() method inside the adapter, ask if the convertView is not null to use it and if not then you inflate the row layout, someting like this: `if (convertView == null) {LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);}` and then use convertView instead of the "row" you are using now. This has nothing to do with your problem is just thing to your code behave better.

Comment: sir , i have a listview which has 6 textviews including an year, and the data which wil be loaded will be hardcoded , which i have already defined inside my strings.xml , so when i select any item on the spinner , say 2010 , i want the defined datas to shown in the listview first , the textview year changes to 2010 or not its a different concern , but first my listview itself is not loading thats the main concern ,for now whatever year displays not a concern ,i want just the listview to be seen on any item selected from the spinner